# what is __NSBlockVariable__ and why it crashes with unrecognized selector sent to instance error?

Tags: objective-c

I've got crash reports of call stack like below. As I cannot re-produce the bug, I have to guess what's happing.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException
---------------------
-[__NSBlockVariable__ profile_data]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab2f620
---------------------
0 CoreFoundation 0x378688a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x35d6e259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2 CoreFoundation 0x3786ba9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 174
3 CoreFoundation 0x3786a915 ___forwarding___ + 300
4 CoreFoundation 0x377c5650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5 TouchPalDialer 0x0005096f -[InfoEditViewControllerNew textFieldDidEndEditing:] + 134
```

The code throwing the crash should be something like

```
profile_data_manager.profile_data.name = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
```

The profile_data_manager is for sure to be of class type ProfileDataManager, and it is for sure to have property@property(nonatomic, retain) ProfileModel *profile_data;

I've no idea why profile_data_manager became a **NSBlockVariable**, and why it does not recognize profile_data.

I saw this post [Calling delegate method, unrecognized selector because sending to wrong object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369895/calling-delegate-method-unrecognized-selector-because-sending-to-wrong-object), says change nonatomic to atomic solves his problem.

I'm not sure if my crash is of the same reason. It would be great if anyone can show me some resource explains about NSBlockVariable, so I can understand the reason better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your project use ARC? I'm assuming not. Make sure you're not over-releasing `profile_data_manager`.

In my experience this type of error means an object has been release prematurely and it's memory has been reused to hold an instance of a new object. In this case, an instance of `NSBlockVariable`.

You could try doing an Analyze build on your project to look for possible refcount (retain/release) errors.

You could also try running your project with zombies turned on... (See the allocations instrument in Instruments and enable the zombies option). This can track down ref count bugs. (Assuming this *is* a refcount bug)... but that seems likely.

Answer (score 0):

Because your object prepare to release by ARC. To resolve, sure you put you variable in global variable, so, it only release when parent object release.